# In Excel How can I count the number of times a substring appears in a colum of text cells?

Tags: excel

I have a column of text strings that have one or a few months of the year written in each cell such as "January; March; November" in A1, "March; October; November; December" in A2, "January; Febraruy" in A3, ...
Is there one Excel formula that can count the number of times that "March" appears in Column A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS with wildcards:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"*"&"March"&"*")
```

Comment: this will only count the number of cells, not the number of Marches.  If a single cell contains 10 Marches, you only get 1

Comment: ^^^^^ That is true.  if the OP has duplicate months in a cell it will only count that cell as 1.  I based this answer on the information given not for every scenerio.  If the OP has duplicates in the cell and want each instance of the word, then please update the question with more information.

Comment: I think, you'll be safe enough with that formula...... if not, maybe `=SUM(LEN(A:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"March","")))/LEN("March")`